# How to make Vue-directive / Vue-filter available in all components of the one page?

Tags: vue.js

please tell me how you can I make the directives / filters available in all components of the one view [vue 2 cli].
Is it right to use a global mixin and write filters/directives there... Or vue-mixins are used only for methods...?

Answer (score 1):

You can define filters globally before creating the Vue instance (new Vue()).

This is copied from the Vue documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html):

```
Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = value.toString()
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
})

new Vue({
  // ...
})
```

To avoid getting to much code in main.js you can also import functions as filters with:

```
import filterA from '<path>'

Vue.filter('<nameOfFilter>', filterA);

new Vue({
  // ...
})
```